How to go about designing a window that can selectively allow light, air, and sound in depending on the occupant's preferences?
The usual combination of window + blind today allows occupants to pick between allowing in external light, blocking external light, allowing external air exchange, blocking air exchange.
I'm curious if like light, it would be possible for an ideal window to toggle allowing a lot of sound versus not a lot of sound from outside in.
A solution I had which wastes a lot of space was the following:

The premise is basically that by making the window into a deep space and  having a gate that can open or close to expose a sound absorbing space one can decide if they want to allow sounds from outside easily in or not, independently of the window. (Note this doesn't filter sounds that are normal to the window pane).
I'm curious if 1. it could be possible to filter normal the pane while still allowing breezes to pass through, 2. can this just be done in a manner that is more space efficient? We do compromise a bit on light by allowing this setup (unless the sound absorbing component can alternate between being very reflective/versus completely light absorbing).

My triple glazing seems to work fine, especially when I tilt the top open for ventilation.
